# Grub issue, boot-repair does not work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've decided to reinstall Ubuntu system. Ubuntu has been installed properly (I guess), but installation of grub failed. I have tried to run boot-repair, and it said that i should paste the following commands:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:i386 shim-signed linux-signed*
```

Unfortunately, the output of first command was

```
Setting up shim-signed (1.21.3+0.9+1465500757.14a5905.is.0.8-0ubuntu3) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.74+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu11) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

As far as I understand the problem is with UEFI, however I do not know how to fix this so that grub will run again.

Comment: First of all, read and understand this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: OK, as far as I understand since I have two systems they both should be in BIOS or in UEFI mode at the same time. When i opened UEFI settings, i checked that it has an option Legacy in boot. Hence both systems were installed in BIOS mode.  If I installed Ubuntu 16.10 in BIOS version, will my problem disappear?

Comment: Most UEFIs have 3 options, one, other or both. Any factory installed Windows 10 is in UEFI mode. Any user installed Windows 10 **should** also be installed in UEFI mode if available. If otherwise, you're right in your assumption.

Comment: I am sorry, but accidentally i realized i was wrong, in fact i have **both** option. By **should** you mean default option? So what i should do is to install Ubuntu in different version?

Comment: If you have both at UEFI settings then you **can't** know what mode Windows was installed just by looking at that. Boot a Ubuntu live session, open GParted and look at the partitions. If there's a small FAT32 partition labeled EFI then it's UEFI mode. Otherwise it's legacy. Boot and install Ubuntu accordingly, i.e., using the same mode the previous OS was installed with. It's that simple!

Comment: I think I understand now:) I checked with gparted and I see only two partitions ntfs so, according to what you've said, i should install Ubuntu in legacy mode. It actually make sense now to me. I will try now to install Ubuntu properly